How to host a MERN stack project in directadmin
I have a completed MERN stack project, and I am going to host this project in DirectAdmin.
There is no problem in frontend. I hosted frontend successfully.
But I'm having trouble connecting to the backend.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backendurl/api/auth/join' from origin 'https://frontendurl' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Of course I found some similar error in here, but it's not working.
And I need an accurate step-by-step guide to hosting a nodejs project as a backend in directadmin.
I can't find any guides and support online.
Thank you.

This question is similar to: XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
